# How to configure an ngnix-location?

Tags: configuration, nginx, location

What I want:

```
 / => /var/www/
 /measurements /var/meassurements
```

what I get using "location":

```
 / => /var/www/
 /measurements => /var/measurements/measurements
```

what am I doing wrong?

**Config-snippet:**

```
location / {                                                               
    # root   /usr/share/nginx/html;                                        
    root /var/www/;                                        
    index  index.html index.htm;                                           
}                                                                          

location /measurements {                                                         
    root   /var/measurements/;                                                
    autoindex on;                                                          
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following should work:

```
location / {                                                               
  # root   /usr/share/nginx/html;                                        
  root /var/www/;                                        
  index  index.html index.htm;                                           
}                                                                          

location /measurements/ {                                                         
  root   /var;                                                
  autoindex on;                                                          
}
```

the reason is that the path is made up out as root + $uri, so your were ending up looking for `/var/measurements/measurements`